# What is the logic behind that one can "grow out of debt" via increase in GDP?

Tags: macroeconomics, government-debt, debt

As we all know the US has a big debt and increasing deficits. The head of FED J. Powell commented that the US was on an unsustainable path w.r.t some debt to GDP ratio. A few commentators I listen to argue that if the US increases it GDP, then they can "grow out of" this problem that Powell mentioned.

Could someone explain this logic to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they invest in productivity-enhancing stuff, GDP could grow at a faster pace than the [increase in] debt. Then the debt to GDP would decrease.